# Resources CPU Memory Bandwith Hard Disk Read and Write With Iframe

Tags: iframe

If i have an `iframe` on a page, that loads images or videos from another site, does it use my server resources or the other server resources? Resources like cpu power, memory (RAM) , bandwidth , and read and write on the hard disk.

Also does memory usage per user functions like bandwidth? the more pageviews user load and the bigger the size of the page in KB than the more bandwidth the user use.

Answer (score 0):

`iframe` loading definitely causes bandwidth issue for remote server as it is called by client browser (just like an URL).

in the case of memory uses per user, when a user loads pages with larger size, he is having more HTTP requests than other and likely have some read/write depending on static/dynamic pages and also with server cache.

Comment: thank u, but what about RAM, does it use RAM if it's in Iframe

Comment: In case of "iframe", it will use the source url provider server's RAM, bandwidth etc.